# JSON.stringify returns {} even with replacer

Tags: javascript, json

My code ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/OldGeezer/w2gzkntv/3/)) is:

```js
let count = 0;
replacer = (k, v) => {
  console.log(`count: ${count++}`);
  if (v === undefined)
    return null;
  else
    return v;
}

try {
  const x = y;
} catch (err) {
  console.log(err);
  console.log("=====");
  console.log(`typeof err is ${typeof err}`);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err));
  console.log("-----");
  console.log(JSON.stringify(err, replacer));
}
```

The output is:

```
ReferenceError: y is not defined
    at window.onload ((index):42)
=====
typeof err is object
{}
-----
count: 0
{}
```

Is `err` really `{}`?  If not, how do I get a JSON string representation of it?

Comment: What browser are you using? I'm getting `{"line":42,"column":18,"sourceURL":"https://fiddle.jshell.net/OldGeezer/w2gzkntv/3/show/"}` in Safari.

Comment: Chrome. @Eddie converted the post to a snippet, but the result output is not the same as the Fiddle's. The snippet gives `{}` for `console.log(err)`.

Comment: It may be that the error object itself has no enumerable properties, they may be on its `[[Prototype]]`, or they might be getters (so are functions and ignored by JSON.stringify). Try *for..in*.

Comment: Chrome, Edge, FF and Opera are showing `{}`, but Safari is showing the expected result, as I said before in my comment. Therefore, this seems to be just a browser implementation difference.

Comment: Maybe the browsers are designed to print `err.stack` instead of `err`

Comment: @RobG Getters aren’t ignored by `JSON.stringify`.

Comment: @SebastianSimon—cool, I've never tried to stringify them. :-)

Comment: @RobG I stand corrected, Safari is showing the *unexpected* result.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the properties of *error* instances are inherited from *Error.prototype* and are not own properties, see [ECMA-262 §19.5.4](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/10.0/#sec-properties-of-error-instances).

Safari has additional properties on the instance itself (*line*, *column*, *sourceURL*), however *name* and *message* are on the prototype.

You can convert it to JSON with your own function, e.g.

```js
// Create plain object, copy error name and message properties.
// Copy own properties of error instance, then JSON.stringify it
function errToJSON(err) {
  let props = Object.assign({name:err.name, message:err.message}, err);
  return JSON.stringify(props);
}

try {
  var x = y;
} catch (e) {
  console.log('JSON.stringify(e):\n' + JSON.stringify(e));
  console.log('errToJSON(e):\n' + errToJSON(e));
  console.log('e.toString():\n' + e.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case err doesn't have any own enumerable properties. Only its prototype ReferenceError. You can inspect err by its inherited properties, like described in [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/ReferenceError)

Answer (score 0):

- It seems that the properties of error instances are inherited from Error.prototype and are not own properties, see ECMA-262 §19.5.4.
- JSON.stringify return {} because the err object is not pure object there is no key value paired. so it would return {}